# 1 viewmodel multiple routes: lifecycle

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I'd like to have a couple of different routes pointing to the same view/viewmodel and I have managed to make this happen.

```
            { route: 'formulation',             moduleId: 'formulation',    title: 'Formulation',       nav: 6 },
            { route: 'fabrication',             moduleId: 'test',           title: 'Fabrication',       nav: 7 },
            { route: 'fabrication/:studyId',    moduleId: 'test',           title: 'Fabrication'               },
            { route: 'characterization',        moduleId: 'test',           title: 'Characterization',  nav: 8 },
```

However, I'm running into a bit of a problem with the lifecycle. I'd like to be notified when the hash changes from one hash to another hash. For example fabrication to characterization. Ideally I could just update a few variables but I'm not against rebuilding the view/viewmodel. The issue is as some of you might know when is when the changing moduleId to is the same as the previous moduleId the activate hook does not fire. How exactly should this be handled. 
Thanks,
 Calvin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to override `areSameItem` on the activator (which is created by the router as `activeItem`). Somewhere early on in the wireup of your application, try doing this:

```
var routerAreSameItem = router.activeItem.settings.areSameItem;

router.activeItem.settings.areSameItem = function (currentItem, newItem, currentActivationData, newActivationData) {
    debugger;
    return routerAreSameItem.apply(this, _.toArray(arguments));
};
```

Obviously this particular implementation isn't going to do anything; but you should be able to provide some custom logic in the `areSameItem` method to distingish the item change.

If my memory serves correctly, returning `false` from that method should make your `activate` method get called.

Comment: Hi gerrod, your memory serves you correctly :-) Do you know if there are any disadvantages by setting this `areSameItem`property to always return `false`

Comment: Not really; if you _want_ activate to fire every time your page loads then this is the way to go (i.e. its by design).