# How to clear view model in Durandal

Tags: javascript, singleton, durandal

Is there a way to selectively tell Durandal to reinitialize a view model. I am aware of the singleton vs new instance approaches to initialize view models.

```
//singleton since a declared object is returned
define(function() {
    return { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }
});

//new instance since a constructor is returned
define(function() {

var ctor = function(){};

    return ctor;
});
```

I generally don't like to declare view models as singletons, but I have to do it in a special case due to sub routing which requires me to pass data from a parent router to my child router. However, the singleton has other side effects, so I was wondering: Is there a way to selectively request a new instance of the view model even if it was initially declared as a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of - this is more of a limitation of requirejs versus Durandal, though. Once require has loaded the module, so far as I know it will always return you the same version of that module. Unless there's a way to tell require to reload the module?

The only thing I could think of would be to "reset" the view model during the `activate` method. If you're changing routes and finding that the `activate` method isn't being called, it may be because Durandal thinks that your module is already active (in which case it won't reactivate). You can change this behavior by customising the `areSameItem` function for the router (see [this question for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077884/1-viewmodel-multiple-routes-lifecycle/22087450#22087450)).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps in your case, but you could use the `activate()` method in your view model. For more information see http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.